# Why, when creating a model for fine tuning, openai says that there is no key?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm training to work with trained models.
First I enter the command:

```
set OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-blablablablablablablabla
```

Then I convert my json file to jsonl:

```
openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f data.json
```

It is being created. But then, when I want to specify this file for fine-tuning, it gives an error:

```
Error: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = <PATH>'. You can gene
```

Although, if I specify a command on the command line immediately with a key, then the model is created:

```
openai -k <YOUR_API_KEY> api fine_tunes.create -t “your_path_to_gpt_prepared.jsonl” -m curie
```

Why is this happening?